# gunicorn: error: argument --error-logfile/--log-file: expected one argument - Procfile

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I run heroku open, it says that there is an application error. I run heroku logs --tails, this comes up:
gunicorn: error: argument --error-logfile/--log-file: expected one argument

I assume it's a problem with my Procfile, because my Procfile has something to do with --log-file.

Heres my Procfile:
web: gunicorn pages_project.wsgi --log-file -

Please help me!